# Check if VARCHAR2 contains only alphabets using trigger

Tags: sql, database, loops, plsql, triggers

I need to write such a trigger that will check name of the person and will print out his/her id if those people have any digits in theirs names.

What I have by now:

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON
create or replace trigger BeforeUpdate
Before insert on customer
for each row 

declare 
n varchar2(10);
counter number;
nextR number:=0;

begin
select count(id_customer) into counter from customer;

LOOP
nextR:= nextR +1;
select cname into n from customer where id_customer = nextR;
if n not like '%[0-9]%' then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nextR || ' has incorrect name');
end if;
exit when nextR = counter;
end loop;
end;
/
```

It compiles and when I am trying to fire this trigger it do nothing.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to get your result.

In your case, if you get a digit in n, your if clause should be executed.

So,

```
if regexp_replace(n,'[^[:digit:]]') IS NOT NULL then      
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nextR || ' has incorrect name');
end if
```

It seems you are also attempting to use a regular expression for digit. However, what your code is searching is for a string that has `[0-9]` in it. Like `Bat[0-9]Man`, which is not your desired result.

In my code, whatever expression is not digit in the given name is being replaced. If the name does not contain any digits, the regular expression would return null. If there is any digit at any place,the expression would return those digits.

You could analyse the following query for better grasping of what is happening here:

```
select regexp_replace(cname,'[^[:digit:]]') OUTP, cname from customer;
```

**EDIT :**

This is not how you write a trigger !

The trigger will be fired each time an insert is going to take place. You don't need the counter. You need to use :NEW reference

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON
create or replace trigger update or
Insert on customer
for each row 

begin
if regexp_replace(:NEW.cname,'[^[:digit:]]') IS NOT NULL then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nextR || ' has incorrect name');
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work as well,
but now I have an idea of what should I use.
 Thanks a lot

Comment: @Yun8483, it did for my sample cases. Ok, go ahead with your attempts :-) The tweak I did would capture stuff like Bat9Man, Bat9Man1 etc.

Comment: yeah, it works perfect) but I was supposed to somehow manage to perform this task in the loop. Although it looks like it is impossible, because in the loop I then have mutation of the table. :C

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

- using `dbms_output` in a trigger doesn't really make sense; usually, the `INSERT` will be performed by client code that doesn't handle the console output. 
  The sensible thing is to raise an exception instead.
- You don't need to perform a `SELECT` in your trigger code. In fact, doing so will usually either be superfluous or raise a mutating table error. Instead, use :new and :old to refer to the values of the row that was inserted
- (minor) naming a before insert trigger `BeforeUpdate` is somewhat confusing
- use a regular expression for testing this business rule (seriously; regexes rule for this kind of thing)

Altogether, here's the fixed version (untested, I don't have an Oracle instance available for testing right now):

```
create or replace trigger TR_BI_CUSTOMER
Before insert on customer
for each row 
begin
  if regexp_like(:new.name, '.*[0-9].*') then 
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Incorrect name: ' || :new.name);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: @I_am_Batman Doh! What a stupid error, thanks for pointing this out. Fixed.

Comment: I accidentally named this trigger BeforeUpdate, I was probably thinking abot before update trigger, whilst doing this one and after all forgot to change the name. I am sorry for it.
I was supposed to use a loop.
And yes I had mutations using select, but I needed to somehow fix it.
But your advices are really helpful. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `REGEXP_LIKE()`!  The regex of `'\d'` matches a number.

```
SQL> with tbl(id, name) as (
      select 1, 'Batman'    from dual union
      select 2, 'Robin1'    from dual union
      select 3, 'Supe4rman' from dual union
      select 4, '3Joker'    from dual
    )
    select id, name bad_name
    from tbl
    where regexp_like(name, '\d');

        ID BAD_NAME
---------- ---------
         2 Robin1
         3 Supe4rman
         4 3Joker

SQL>
```

If your goal is to strip out the digits on the way in (but be careful, a company really could have a number in the name like Level3 Communications or 3Com, if it's a person its less likely but these days who knows!)  This is untested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_bu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON customer
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- If the new name contains a digit, strip it.
  if regexp_like(:new.name, '\d') then
    :new.name := regexp_replace(:new.name, '\d', NULL);
  end if;

END customer_bu;
/
```

Comment: I don't why, but in my case it works exactly vice-versa. I think that is because of my code. I will try to fix and implement this method. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Oh you WANT numbers in the names? I might have it reversed.